# Coincident Bivariate Map with Squares

Tags: python, colorbar, cartopy

I want to display temperature change and uncertainty in the same map with Cartopy in Python. I would like to have the temperature change indicated by colors (cmap = 'coolwarm') and the uncertainty by the size of the squares... The colorbar schould look like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEE9k.png). So far, I could only find how to overlay two colormaps to create a 2D colormap, but not how to use color vs. size. Is there any package that might help or is it possible to do this just with maptlotlib and cartopy?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using Matplotlibs [hatches](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/shapes_and_collections/hatch_style_reference.html) to basically overplot some white gridded pattern on top of your data. I'm not sure how to make the hatches align nicely between the different "densities".

Generating some sample data:

```
def sample_data(nlats=180, nlons=360):
    # https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/scalar_data/waves.html#sphx-glr-gallery-scalar-data-waves-py

    lats, lons = np.mgrid[-np.pi/2:np.pi/2:np.pi/nlats, 0:2*np.pi:2*np.pi/nlons]    
    wave = 0.75 * (np.sin(2 * lats) ** 8) * np.cos(4 * lons)
    mean = 0.5 * np.cos(2 * lats) * ((np.sin(2 * lats)) ** 2 + 2)
    
    return np.rad2deg(lons), np.rad2deg(lats), wave + mean

lons, lats, data = sample_data()

_, _, uncert = sample_data(360,720)
uncert = uncert.T[:180, :360]
```

Plotting:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5), dpi=86, subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.EckertIII()))

ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines('110m', alpha=0.5)

img = ax.contourf(lons, lats, data, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=0.8, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
pat = ax.contourf(lons, lats, uncert, hatches=['+'*1, '+'*2, '+'*3, '+'*4], alpha=1.0, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

for p in pat.collections:
    p.set_facecolor('none')
    p.set_edgecolor('w')
    p.set_linewidth(0.0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That seems very promising and mostly works for me. However, I also still have some trouble with the alignment as well and am not sure if my uncertainty data is correctly depicted by the hatches. The problem might be in my data, though. 
I also tried out Matplotlibs scatter, where you can define the size of the different markers with a list of values. Biut I had to bring the data into a different form to be able to use scatter, so it does not seem like the most elegant option.